# Firefox 90 breaks display of `object` SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg, firefox

I have a website that shows an SVG using an `object` tag, as an overlay to an image on mouse-hover.

This worked fine in all major browser, but it just broke in Firefox after upgrading from 89 to 90.

Here's an example where you should see in action using Chrome, Safari, Edge, or Firefox < 90:

https://www.astrobin.com/150857/B/

If you mouse-hover the image, you will see an overlay that shows a sky grid and circles and names around the identified galaxies.

In Firefox 90 this doesn't seem to work anymore.

This is a minimal reproduction fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/6xrv80bk/ (works in Chrome and Firefox 89, doesn't work in Firefox 90)

Any idea why that could be?

Thanks!

Comment: Create a minimised testcase and report it to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=SVG

Comment: Thanks, will do it. I added a minimal fiddle to the question.

Comment: A regression range found using https://mozilla.github.io/mozregression/ would also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I started with a report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1720986

Comment: I'm running the bisect using mozregression and will update the bug with the result, thanks.